# Creating event in eventbridge when an RDS instance is started

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to learn and play a bit with aws serevices. I want to create a rule in the eventbridge that would simply lanch a lambda function when an rds database instance is started.

Here is the rule I use:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "detail-type": "RDS DB Instance Event",
  "source": "aws.rds",
  "region": "eu-south-2",
  "resources": ["XXX"],
  "detail": {
    "EventCategories": ["notification"],
    "SourceType": "DB_INSTANCE",
    "SourceArn": "XXX",
    "Message": "DB instance started.",
    "EventID": "RDS-EVENT-0088"
  }
}
```

I get an error "Event pattern is not valid. Reason: "version" must be an object or an array at... "
I guess it is a formating error, but literally can't figure it out... I'm just passing a string. When I try to test the pattern from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-cloud-watch-events.html) I get the same error.

It is probably something very stupid, but I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is wrong.

This is the not the rule but an example of event which will be matched by rule.

You can actually create a rule by doing the following:-

- go to eventbridge , create rule
- select event source as aws
- choose sample events type as enter my own and enter the below mentioned event ( this is the event which is generated when instance is started as per title of questions). to check other event id, follow [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html#USER_Events.Messages.instance)
- 0088 event id is the event when rds instance is started

  ```
   {
      "version": "0",
      "id": "68f6e973-1a0c-d37b-f2f2-94a7f62ffd4e",
      "detail-type": "RDS DB Instance Event",
      "source": "aws.rds",
      "account": "123456789012",
      "time": "2018-09-27T22:36:43Z",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "resources": ["arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24"],
      "detail": {
        "EventCategories": ["failover"],
        "SourceType": "DB_INSTANCE",
        "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24e",
        "Date": "2018-09-27T22:36:43.292Z",
        "SourceIdentifier": "rds:mysql-instance-2018-10-06-12-24",
        "Message": "A Multi-AZ failover has completed.", // Message would be something else
        "EventID": "RDS-EVENT-0088"
      }
    }
  ```
- create a custom pattern and use the following json.

  ```
    {

     "source": ["aws.rds"],
     "detail-type": ["RDS DB Instance Event"],
      "detail": {
                   "EventID": ["RDS-EVENT-0088"]
                 }
    }
  ```

If you test this rule, for the event above mentioned it will match.

how to find sample event [ as per comments ]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now. And I think I understand it better now.

I have one more small question. Is it possible to gather sample events from aws services directly from logs or in some other way? I have currently no idea what kind of keys I can use for the events.

Comment: the simplest way to gather samples event will be under eventbridge rule -> create rule -> rule with event pattern. Here you can find sample event 

Select aws events -> select service for which you want to find sample event.


I have attached an image too and updated my answer.